# Graph of $f(x)=|x|(\sin x)^{1/5}$ near $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

I would like to find the graph of $f(x)=|x|(\sin x)^{1/5}$ near x=0. How can I deduce the right inflection point without calculating the second derivative?

### A: [image] B: [image] C:[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble distinguishing the graphs. What is the tangent's slope at the origin? Also please add what you tried so that we can help you.

Comment: The difference between the first one and the third one is that in the first one there's a slant asymptote. I tried solving it using the second derivative, but it seems a little bit long in terms of calculations, since it is supposed to be only a multiple choice question.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between options A and C. The illustration of A has a tangent drawn in, but the actual _curve_ on C looks pretty identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an odd function approximating $x^{6/5}$ for small $x>0$, with an even derivative approximating $\frac65 x^{1/5}$ for such $x$. The former fact excludes $B$, because the exponent $>1$; the latter fact excludes $A$, whose gradient at the origin is nonzero.